# WiFi won't work after updating to kernel 4.10.0-24

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom, 17.04, bug-reporting

My laptop running on Kubuntu cannot use WiFi (Broadcom) after updating from 4.10.0-22.  Did anyone experience the same issue as me?

Comment: really this should be reported as a bug: ubuntu-bug linux

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, downgrade to 4.10.0-22 helped.

Running Ubuntu Budgie and I'm using an Intel 7265 WLAN module.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I did